# SUMPRODUCT with a LEFT & AND - Excel

Tags: excel, sumproduct

Is it possible to combined Sumproduct, left and a AND function all together in Excel.

I have the below formula working correctly - but i want to add in the additional reviews which also = "88"

="Number Reviews: "&SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(M:M,2)="77"))

Is there a way to add in an "and" function which allows me to sum up all of 77 and 88 altogether?

& If this is possible - if i wanted to add up the remaining totals which are not 77 or 88, is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify the question, consider adding sample data and provide your current out as well as the output you want.

Comment: Is the data in column M stored as numbers or text? If text, COUNTIF would be a lot more efficient; if numbers, you should really avoid using entire columns with a formula like that. But to address your question: `="Number Reviews: "&SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(M:M,2)={"77","88"}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, this should work.

**Sum up all of 77 and 88 altogether :**

> ="Number Reviews: "&SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(M:M,2)="77")) + SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(M:M,2)="88"))

**Which are not 77 or 88 :**

Assuming you have Header in the data

> =COUNTA(M:M)-(SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(M:M,2)="77")) + SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(M:M,2)="88")))-1

Comment: Perfect. Thank you !